# Huge performance difference on using fields to build EF Queries

Tags: entity-framework

I noticed some huge performances difference by using **fields to build the Query**. For example:

Performance **with** fields: DB Reads: 21118, Duration: 156

Performance **without** fields: DB Reads: 8113, Duration: 29

---

Code example **with** fields

```
var newStatus = OrderStatus.New.ToString();
var inProgressStatus = OrderStatus.InProgress.ToString();
var inReview = OrderStatus.InReview.ToString();

var data = ctx.COM_Order
  .Select(o => new QueryModel
  {
      Order = o,
      SortPrio = (o.COM_OrderStatus.StatusName == newStatus
      || o.COM_OrderStatus.StatusName == inProgressStatus
      || o.COM_OrderStatus.StatusName == inReview
      ? 1 : 2),

      ClassNames = o.COM_OrderItem
          .Join(CMS_Tree, orderItem => orderItem.OrderItemSKUID, tree => tree.NodeSKUID,
          (oi, t) => t.CMS_Class.ClassName),

        UDM_LegalData = UDM_LegalData.Where(d => o.COM_Customer.CustomerID == d.CustomerID).FirstOrDefault(),
        UDM_OrderStatusHistory = UDM_OrderStatusHistory.Where(h => h.OrderId == o.OrderID),
  });
```

SQL output: http://pastie.org/10391835

Code example **without** fields

```
var data = ctx.COM_Order
.Select(o => new QueryModel
{
    Order = o,
    SortPrio = (o.COM_OrderStatus.StatusName == "New"
    || o.COM_OrderStatus.StatusName == "InProgress"
    || o.COM_OrderStatus.StatusName == "InReview"
    ? 1 : 2),

    ClassNames = o.COM_OrderItem
        .Join(CMS_Tree, orderItem => orderItem.OrderItemSKUID, tree => tree.NodeSKUID,
        (oi, t) => t.CMS_Class.ClassName),

        UDM_LegalData = UDM_LegalData.Where(d => o.COM_Customer.CustomerID == d.CustomerID).FirstOrDefault(),
        UDM_OrderStatusHistory = UDM_OrderStatusHistory.Where(h => h.OrderId == o.OrderID),
});
```

SQL output: http://pastie.org/10391839

Why is there this huge performance difference and can I use fields/enums without performance drawbacks?

Thanks

- Tested with EF version 6.0.2 and 6.1.3

---

**Update 1**

- added sql output
- updated the example queries to the “full EF queries” (I was not able to reproduce the performance differences with the downgraded example queries)

**Update 2**

- added EF version information

Comment: Did you look at the generated SQL to see how they differ?

Comment: I doubt that you examine the queries **the first time** when they are both compiled and run. The first query of course should require more steps to build the Expression tree behind the scene so it's just the difference in time to build the Expression tree. You can try testing it after the first time running. Since EF 5, the query is cached so since the second running, there won't be no steps building the Expression tree.

Comment: What do you mean for reads? SQL Server reads (from the profiler)? Can you send the whole model (at least COM_Order, order status and the controller)? I'd like to investigate to understand this behaviour because in this case the expression tree should be very similar and the query should be the same.

Comment: Which EF version is this?

Comment: from the first generated query this `CASE WHEN ((([Extent2].[StatusName] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Extent2].[StatusName] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent2].[StatusName] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)) OR (([Extent2].[StatusName] = @p__linq__1) AND ( NOT ([Extent2].[StatusName] IS NULL OR @p__linq__1 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent2].[StatusName] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL)) OR (([Extent2].[StatusName] = @p__linq__2) AND ( NOT ([Extent2].[StatusName] IS NULL OR @p__linq__2 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent2].[StatusName] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__2 IS NULL))) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS [C1]`...

Comment: is much more complicated than `CASE WHEN (((N'New' = [Extent2].[StatusName]) AND ([Extent2].[StatusName] IS NOT NULL)) OR ((N'InProgress' = [Extent2].[StatusName]) AND ([Extent2].[StatusName] IS NOT NULL)) OR ((N'InReview' = [Extent2].[StatusName]) AND ([Extent2].[StatusName] IS NOT NULL))) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS [C1]` from the second query.

Comment: The auto-query seems not very efficient. It assumes fields could be null, so it takes that into consideration when comparing string. As I remember there is an option in database side which can change the null comparison behavior. Also the Expression tree building time should add up the final difference (not just the final SQL query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is there this huge performance difference

Questions about why or why not about implementations of third-party components are always hard to answer by anything else than "because".

Apparently, SQL generation takes a different turn when variables are involved than with values. I don't know why and I'm not going to guess.

What I do know is that you can force a better query shape by using `Contains`:

```
var statuses = new[] { newStatus, inProgressStatus, inReview };
var data = ctx.COM_Order
  .Select(o => new QueryModel
  {
      Order = o,
      SortPrio = statusses.Contains(o.COM_OrderStatus.StatusName) ? 1 : 2),
      ...
```

This will always translate into an `IN` statement.

Comment: Hi Gert, with your approach by using 'Contains' EF generates the fast query. Nice! And your other words hits exactly the point ;) Thanks.